# WooCommerce sends order confirmation to customer every few minutes

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

My WooCommerce shop keeps sending order confirmation mails every (around) 10 minutes to a certain customer. And it does not stop.

I already changed the order status to "on hold", but it does not help. Is there a way to tell WooCommerce or the server to stop sending these emails?

Answer (score 0):

I believe WordPress emails run on a Cron that shoots out emails to everything "flagged" within the table. I am not sure what it is off the top of my head, but you might be able to manually go into the MySQL table and just alter that data for his order.

This link may help, too:
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/email-faq/

Comment: where do I find "flagged" entries. There is not something obvious to me in the wp_posts or wp_postmeta

Comment: I would think that it would be in the Order or Order meta, not the post.

Comment: I bet if you look in the backend it will still show it as Pending for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for help. Actually it was Zapier who caused the trouble :)

Answer (score 0):

So,

I don't know if this helps anyone because it seems a rare case. But with our webshop it was zapier. We created a zap that hooks to the order confirmation mails. Deactivating this zap solved the problem.